# MySQL get most popular tags ids combination with their counts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

*I have three tables*

**1.tbl_tag**

```
id int NOT NULL AI PK
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

> content

```
id name
1 lifestyle
2 store
3 car
4 luxury
5 classy
6 boy
7 girl
8 man
9 woman
10 strong
etc ...
```

**2.tbl_media**

```
id int NOT NULL AI PK
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

> content

```
id name
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
6 six
7 seven
8 eight
9 nine
10 ten
etc...
```

**3. tbl_media_tag**

```
id int NOT NULL AI PK
media_id int NOT NULL -> relationship with tbl_media
tag_id int NOT NULL -> relationship with tbl_tag
```

> content

```
id media_id tag_id
1 1 4
2 1 3
3 4 3
4 5 2
5 6 8
6 4 4
7 8 7
8 7 4
9 7 3
10 6 2
11 8 4
12 8 3
etc...
```

I want to get most popular tags(tag_id) combinations with LIMIT, for example most popular top ten tags combination

I want to get result like this

```
4, 7, 3 (75)
4, 8 (42)
1, 7, 9, 10 (28)
7, 8, 9 (10)
7, 2 (2)
```

Comment: Can you replace the numbers from the result in appropriate string from tbl_tag so that it will be more clear to know what result you are expecting

Comment: If we can resolve it by this way, it will be great. But if we can't, I can change my media table, and add **tags** column, where I will store tags collection string **(car, lifestyle, girl, man, etc...)**. And then we can resolve our question by this way - We will try to find most popular word combination form media, in **tags** column, we will have result like 
`car, life, style (24)
girl, lifestyle (12)
luxury, classy, business, lifestyle (7)
etc...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT tag_sum,
           COUNT(*) as tag_sum_count
    FROM 
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag_id 
                             ORDER BY tag_id DESC 
                             SEPARATOR ',') as tag_sum,
              media_id
        FROM tbl_media_tag mt
        GROUP BY media_id) sub
    GROUP BY tag_sum) sub2
ORDER BY tag_sum_count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank you very much STANISLAV, BROTHER! 
Great MySQL knowledge!